# windows phone 8 c# httpclient dosent send request for second time

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8, httpclient

i am trying for a simple app in windows phone 8.1. i have a button and on first time click it send a request to insert data into the database via url in php. on second click it delete the data from the same table in database via another url in php. when i first run it. it send me the following response from httpclient response

```
 StatusCode:200, ReasonPhase:'ok',   
 version:0.0,content:  
 System.Net.Http.streamContent,headers:  
   {  
    Date:thu,04 jun 2015 08:29:50 GMT  
    server:apache  
    server:phusion_passage/4.0.10  
        server: mod_bwlimited/1.4/5  
    server:mod_fcgid/2.3.9  
    X-powered-by:PHP/5.4/5.4.36  
    Keep-Alive:timeout=3,max=30  
    connection:keep-alive  
    Transfer-encoding:chunked  
    content-Type:text/html  
   }
```

and on second click i also get the same response for deleting. if i again press the button i some how get the following msg

```
StatusCode:200, ReasonPhase:'ok',
version:0.0,content:
System.Net.Http.streamContent,headers:
{
    X-powered-by:PHP/5.4/5.4.36
    Keep-Alive:timeout=3,max=30
    Transfer-encoding:chunked
    content-Type:text/html
}
```

and obviously no data is inserted into the database.

i am in emergency to launch it as this is a small part of a big project.
my code is as follows:

declaration:

```
 url = "http://demo.in/customer_info.php?";
            url_delete = "http://demo.in/delete_noti.php?device_id=";

data1 = url + "device_id=4000";

data_delete = url_delete + "4000";
```

method:

```
   private async void sendData(string data)
    {
       // MessageBox.Show(data1);
        using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await hc.GetAsync(data);
            MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
            hc.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private async void deleteData(string data)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(url_delete1);
        using (HttpClient hc = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await hc.GetAsync(data);
            //MessageBox.Show(hc1.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
            hc.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
private void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            sendData(data1);
            (sender as Button).Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(225, 247, 98, 15));
            MessageBox.Show("sending");
            //    suspend(a);
            count = 1;
        }
        else
        {

            deleteData(url_delete);

            (sender as Button).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            MessageBox.Show("deleting");
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might be a caching issue . try by adding an additional query parameter to the url . url=url+"&ticks" +dateTime.Now.Ticks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Null Pointer suggested, it might be a caching issue.

You can add a random parameter to the url as he said or you can add this line of code to ignore cache if you don't or can't add parameter to the url:

```
hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: ya tried this thnx for the rly..... act the httpclient temporary register the previous url for a time period of 30 by default and if u resend it, the httpclient act as i hv dn this task.....the actual reason :)